# Placing ads in my android app

Tags: android, ads

I am planning to create an android application that may contain some ads. The ads shall be pushed from a web site that hosted in my server. I can push different ads from my server and the users of the application can be able to like, dislike the ads. Based on the user's like/dislike input I can create a rating for the product.

Have anybody did the same things before.

Is there any specific controls in the android stack for this? Can I use Android App widget for this?

Comment: May be adMod sdk can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you need more than a custom ad view , a db and network calls.

The whole idea I think it would be:

1. create the ad view with buttons.
2. onButtonPressed() stores the like or dislike value to the db
3. and fire the server sync.

Android Widget is limited, but it can do these simple things too.

:)